# Why can we inherit `typing.NamedTuple`?

Tags: python, python-typing, namedtuple

After Python 3.6, we have [`typing.NamedTuple`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.NamedTuple), which is a typed version of [`collections.namedtuple()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple), we can inherit it like a class:

```
class Employee(NamedTuple):
    name: str
    id: int
```

Compared with `collections.namedtuple`, this syntax is more beautiful, but I still can't understand its implementation, whether we look at `typing.py` file, or do some simple tests, we will find that it is a function rather than a class:

```
# Python 3.10.6 typing.py
def NamedTuple(typename, fields=None, /, **kwargs):
    """..."""
    if fields is None:
        fields = kwargs.items()
    elif kwargs:
        raise TypeError("Either list of fields or keywords"
                        " can be provided to NamedTuple, not both")
    try:
        module = sys._getframe(1).f_globals.get('__name__', '__main__')
    except (AttributeError, ValueError):
        module = None
    return _make_nmtuple(typename, fields, module=module)
```

```
>>> type(NamedTuple)
<class 'function'>
```

I understand that it uses some metaclass magic, but I don't understand what happens when using `class MyClass(NamedTuple)`. For this reason, I have tried to customize a function to inherit:

```
>>> def func_for_inherit(*args, **kwargs):
...     print(args, kwargs)
...
>>> class Foo(func_for_inherit):
...     foo: str
...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: function() argument 'code' must be code, not str
```

Well, this got a result that I can't understand. When inheriting a user-defined function, it seems that its class was called. What happened behind this?

Comment: @azro I know it's not a class, but I wonder how it behaves *like* a class?

Comment: FYI, `collections.namedtuple` is also a function

Comment: @RafazZ: It is, but you can't do `class Whatever(collections.namedtuple):` and have that work.

Comment: Oh I see what you mean. TBH, I look at the `collections.namedtuple` as a factory; while I see the `typing.NamedTuple` as a class that the said factory generates (or an instance of it). I know that this is not technically true, but that's how my brain is dealing with ignorance :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`typing.NamedTuple` uses a really esoteric feature, [`__mro_entries__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#resolving-mro-entries):

> If a base that appears in class definition is not an instance of `type`, then an `__mro_entries__` method is searched on it. If found, it is called with the original bases tuple. This method must return a tuple of classes that will be used instead of this base. The tuple may be empty, in such case the original base is ignored.

Immediately after the `NamedTuple` function definition, the following code appears:

```
_NamedTuple = type.__new__(NamedTupleMeta, 'NamedTuple', (), {})

def _namedtuple_mro_entries(bases):
    if len(bases) > 1:
        raise TypeError("Multiple inheritance with NamedTuple is not supported")
    assert bases[0] is NamedTuple
    return (_NamedTuple,)

NamedTuple.__mro_entries__ = _namedtuple_mro_entries
```

This sets `NamedTuple.__mro_entries__` to a function that tells the class creation system to use an actual class, `_NamedTuple`, as the base class. (`_NamedTuple` then uses metaclass features to customize the class creation process further, and the end result is a class that directly inherits from `tuple`.)

Comment: Well, it seems that I only focus on the function itself and forget to look around it. The magic of all this seems to have nothing to do with the function itself but lies in this `__mro_entries__`.